# IBM Quantum: Are ibmq_5_yorktown and ibmqx2 different devices?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

When I run `provider.backends()`, `ibmqx2` is listed as an available backend, but is not listed on the [IBMQ systems page](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services?services=systems). [This file](https://github.com/Qiskit/ibmq-device-information/tree/master/backends/yorktown/V1) from the archived repository [ibmq-device-information](https://github.com/Qiskit/ibmq-device-information) associates backend name `ibmqx2` with display name IBM Q 5 Yorktown. The IBMQ systems page does list a 5 qubit Yorktown device, but under the name [ibmq_5_yorktown](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services?services=systems&system=ibmqx2). This backend is also available via `ibmq/open/main`, but is not listed by `provider.backends()`. Are `ibmqx2` and `ibmq_5_yorktown` respectively versions 1 and 2 of backend software providing access to a single Yorktown device? Or do these names refer to two distinct Yorktown devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `ibmqx2` and Yorktown are one quantum processor. When IBM Quantum platform was released, two processors - Yorktown and Tenerife were available. These processor were denoted also `ibmqx2` and `ibmqx4`, respectivelly. Note that Tenerife processor is retired now.

If you have a look into IBM Quantum environment, you can see that there is `ibmqx2` processor in list of available devices. See here:

[image]

When you click on `ibmqx2`, this page is shown:

[image]

So, it means that `ibmqx2` and Yorktown are identical devices.
The naming is just a legacy of former times.

*I would be happy if anybody from IBM can add more comments.*

Answer (score 2):

As @Martin Vesely answered, it is the same device.

Here is the README documentation showing that they are the same: https://github.com/Qiskit/ibmq-device-information/blob/master/backends/yorktown/V1/README.md

Here is a little screen shot of that documentation:

[image]